# How to add a note that is different from the previous note?

Tags: java, android

I have a MainActiviy and a NoteEditorActivity. When I add a note, it resets all of my edit texts to null. However, the edit texts are still linked to each other and the text in one edit text mirrors the other in a different note. How do I make it so that the edit text is both reset to null and a different entity from the already created edit text?

I've already figured out how to set the new edit text to null. However, I have not figured out a solution to differentiating between the edit texts.

This is in my NoteEditorActivity

```java
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_table_note_editor);

        EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.titleViewInput);

        et1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        et2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.textView2);

        loadSavedPreferences();

        Intent intent = getIntent();
        noteId = intent.getIntExtra("noteId", -1);

        if(noteId != -1){

            editText.setText(MainActivity.notes.get(noteId));

        } else {

            MainActivity.notes.add("");
            noteId = MainActivity.notes.size() - 1;
            MainActivity.arrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            et1.setText(null);
            et2.setText(null);
        }
```

Comment: It probably has to do with the lines 
        et1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        et2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.textView2);
As you are setting their values globally, thus probably why you are seeing its values persist after you clear the text

Comment: I have to have those be global as instance variables so I can save them with shared preferences. Do you think an arraylist would be helpful to distinguish between the notes? The problem is that when I create a new note the value is null. When I type a value in, it changes both edit texts in note 1 and 2 to the same value.